# Tridion 8 UI extension: Message stuck on screen after msg.finish({ success: true });

Tags: gui-extensions

As part of the upgrade from version 7 to 8.5, we are upgrading our UI extensions. Since version 8 (is reproducing also on 8.5), we have an issue with messages stuck on screen:

Case1 - message stuck on screen:

```
var msg = $messages.registerProgress("Loading SEO Settings", "Loading SEO    Settings...", true, true, true);
msg.setOnSuccessMessage("Loaded SEO Settings", "SEO Settings loaded.");
msg.setTitle("Checking  publication metadata schema");
msg.setTitle("Seo metadata schema loaded.");
msg.setTitle("Publication schema link component loaded.");
msg.finish({ success: true });
```

The result is that a message is stuck on screen even after the data is loaded and shown on page. On notifications, there are 2 messages, 1 finished, 1 pending.

Case2 - message closed properly

```
var msgLoad = $messages.registerProgress("Loading Language Switcher", "Loading Language Switcher Settings...", true, true, true);
msgLoad.setOnSuccessMessage("Loaded Language Switcher", "Language Switcher Settings loaded.");
msgLoad.finish({ success: true });
```

Case3 - message stuck on screen:

```
var msgSave = $messages.registerProgress("Saving Language Switcher", "Saving Language Switcher Settings...", true, true, true);
msgSave.setOnSuccessMessage("Saved Language Switcher", "Language Switcher Settings saved.");
msgSave.finish({ success: true });
var msgLoad = $messages.registerProgress("Loading Language Switcher", "Loading Language Switcher Settings...", true, true, true);
msgLoad.setOnSuccessMessage("Loaded Language Switcher", "Language Switcher Settings loaded.");
msgLoad.finish({ success: true });
```

The load message is properly closed (like in Case2), but the save message is stuck on screen.